# Get the address for f.seek()?

Tags: python

I'd like to get the address for a hex byte in a file, for example to change all FF bytes into AF.

So, I first have to find some matching byte sequence. How do I do that?

Actually, I tried

```
import re
target = 0x76c0
f = open("bin.dat", 'rb+')
data = f.read()
match = re.search(target, data)
if match:
    print "Found."
    data.replace(target,0xffff)
else:
    print "No match"
f.close()
```

to find and replace it, but somehow python complains about the f.close().
So I started another approach using f.seek() and f.write, but I need the address of the first byte match.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Is this all you want to do with the file? Or will you be performing other operations?

Comment: I just want to modify some bytes of a bin file, meaning, find byte pattern of constant length, modify it (same length) and save the file. Appending nothing.

Comment: If you want to write to the file, the second argument to open needs to include 'w'.